# Is it possible to prevent Doxygen from outputting protected members?

Tags: doxygen, protected

As the title suggests, is it possible to automatically remove protected members from DOxygen output?

I can see options to include private members but no mention of protected members?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Along with `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO`, use the following additional settings:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES
PREDEFINED = protected=private
```

Source: http://osdir.com/ml/text.doxygen.general/2004-12/msg00047.html

Comment: This answer appears to be the standard answer to this question, but it doesn't work for me. Protected members are still showing up. Any ideas?